# wildfly-maven-plugin not deploying when multiple profiles selected

Tags: maven, deployment, wildfly

I am working on a POM.xml to deploy WAR files to a Wildfly server depending on what apps that environment has installed. The project I work with has 3 different applications, and an environment could have between 1 and 3 of these apps installed.

So, I've made profiles for each of the apps -- If app A is installed, run the app A profile to deploy the A app to the server. If B is installed, run the app B profile, etc.

The problem is that when I run my Maven build with more than one app, (e.g. app A and app B), it only deploys one of them. If I run separate Maven builds on each profile individually, it deploys fine. I *think* my problem is with the maven-wildfly-plugin itself, as when running with multiple profiles, they show as active when using the Maven `help:active-profiles` option:

```
[INFO] 
Active Profiles for Project 'com.foo.bar:auto-deploy:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:

 - wildfly-deploy-a (source: com.foo.bar:auto-deploy:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
 - wildfly-deploy-b (source: com.foo.bar:auto-deploy:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
```

The output of the build itself is as follows:

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Auto-Deploy Wildfly 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ auto-deploy ---
[INFO] Installing C:\..........\AutoDeploy\pom.xml to C:\.....\.m2\repository\com\foo\bar\auto-deploy\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\auto-deploy-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ auto-deploy ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha11:deploy-artifact (deploy-a) @ auto-deploy ---
Apr 03, 2017 5:31:52 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO version 3.3.1.Final
Apr 03, 2017 5:31:52 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.1.Final
Apr 03, 2017 5:31:53 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
[INFO] Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- wildfly-maven-plugin:1.1.0.Alpha11:deploy-artifact (deploy-b) @ auto-deploy ---
[INFO] Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.615 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-03T17:32:06-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/210M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this case, both the `deploy-a` and `deploy-b` profiles appear to run, but only the app for `deploy-b` is successfully deployed. My POM.xml is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>auto-deploy</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Auto-Deploy Wildfly</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <wildfly.deploy.version>1.0.2.Final</wildfly.deploy.version>
        <wildfly.hostname>localhost</wildfly.hostname>
        <wildfly.mgmt.native.port>9999</wildfly.mgmt.native.port>               
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-a</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
            <artifactId>app-b</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.Alpha11</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <force>true</force>
                        <protocol>remote</protocol>
                        <hostname>${wildfly.hostname}</hostname>
                        <port>${wildfly.mgmt.native.port}</port>
                        <username>${wildfly.mgmt.username}</username>
                        <password>${wildfly.mgmt.password}</password>
                        <timeout>120</timeout>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>wildfly-deploy-a</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                            <artifactId>app-a</artifactId>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>deploy-a</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        ...
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>wildfly-deploy-b</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                            <artifactId>app-b</artifactId>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>deploy-b</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        ...
        </profile>  
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And I am executing it using `mvn deploy -Pwildfly-deploy-a,wildfly-deploy-b`. The order in which I pass the profiles to Maven does not seem to matter -- it always deploys the app defined in the last profile in the POM (so app b). I have also tried `mvn deploy -Pwildfly-deploy-a -Pwildfly-deploy-b` and that does not work either.

Am I violating some Maven best practices or something here? Everything I've researched today indicates that this should work, which is why I have an inkling that the plugin is causing this behavior.

**EDIT** -- I've also tried mixing it up by making one of the profiles use the `deploy` goal and the other use the `deploy-artifact` goal but I get the same behavior. Could this be some network or threading issue?

**EDIT 2** -- Other weird behavior: when both profiles use the `deploy` goal as opposed to `deploy-artifact`, *neither* of the apps gets deployed...when run individually using `deploy` they will deploy fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin configuration cannot be merged; the second will always override the first.

The trick is to move the configuration into the execution section:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>wildfly-deploy-a</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy-a</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                                <artifactId>app-a</artifactId>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    ...
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>wildfly-deploy-b</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>deploy-b</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
                                <artifactId>app-b</artifactId>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    ...
    </profile>  
</profiles>
```

Now each execution has it's own configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me! Now is moving the configuration into the execution block standard for any Maven plugin (when using profiles)?

Comment: It's independent of profiles. You can actually split the configuration and put the static section (such as `<skip>false</skip>`) where you had it before and just have the execution specific configuration in the new location. With some plugins you may run a sequence of executions, possibly in different phases.